# How to find all assemblies that reference a specific dll?

Tags: c#, dependencies, assemblies, ildasm

I've a directory with a large number of `dlls`. I need to find all those that reference a specific `dll`.

I'm thinking about the following solution :

1. Loop the assemblies and invoke each one with `ildasm`
2. Dump the `manifest` into a text file
3. Search the text files for the required assembly name.

Yet this solution feels immensely wrong to me.  Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: You could use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write a small tool for that purpose, using Reflection to find the referenced assemblies:

```
string[] fileNames = ...; // get all the filenames
foreach (string fileName in fileNames) {
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileName);
    var referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    foreach (var assemblyName in referencedAssemblies) {
        // do your comparison
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Much better indeed

Comment: @Dirk ,How can we load assembly from GAC and get reference ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentationnn AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain. [About AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc9a3791-831c-4135-bb24-1ee4af506ca8/problem-with-appdomaincurrentdomaingetassemblies-in-test-mode?forum=csharplanguage)

It seems that you need to change strategy of loading the asseblies you need from using the appdomain to looking for dlls in your applications folder.

I found a discuss on similar problem [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Download AsmSpy.exe, it has the option to list all assemblies and all the references within the assemblies.

https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy

Answer (score 0):

Download IlSpy.exe, and open the assembly whose references you want to see, it will list all referenced assemblies.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases